# How to update my driver initialization to avoid deprecation warning?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

The warning I'm receiving is: `WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] [:capabilities_hash] passing a Hash value to :capabilities is deprecated. Use Capabilities instance initialized with the Hash, or build values with Options class instead.`

My driver setup looks like:

```
Capybara.register_driver :aws_chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.read_timeout = 180
  capabilities = {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'aws:maxDurationSecs': 2400
  }
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote, http_client: client, url: remote_url, capabilities: capabilities)
end
```

I'm not sure what a capabilities instance is supposed to be, and there's no documentation on how to use the Options class that I could find. I also need to be able to set the `browserName` to `firefox` as needed, so I'm not sure if the Options class is specific to chrome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ruby, but for using options instead of capabilities try:

```
Capybara.register_driver :aws_chrome do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.read_timeout = 180
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_option('aws:maxDurationSecs', 2400)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :remote, http_client: client, url: remote_url, options: options)
end
```

This is Options class api doc for selenium 4:

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Options.html

Comment: This worked for me, except the last parameter has to be `capabilities: options`. Thanks.